# How to add an ajax/jquery file to a wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am doing a wordpress plugin for a registration form. I want to validate my form by ajax and jquery. I wrote the ajax/jquery js file and name it user_ajax.js, but when i include it in my main plugin, it doesn't work and $ is not defined error also comes.

please help me i stuck here for 4 days...

Comment: Use jQuery with a capital Q instead of $ to make it work.

Comment: Put jQuery.noConflict(); and use jQuery instead of $.

Comment: where i put jQuery.noConflict()? in main plugin file.

Answer (score 0):

Register your script in wordpress like this way http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script

```
    function my_plugin_admin_init() {
            /* Register our script. */
            wp_register_script( 'my-plugin-script', plugins_url( '/ user_ajax.js', __FILE__ ) );

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');  // Enqueue jQuery that's already built into WordPress
wp_enqueue_script('my-plugin-script');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_admin_init');
```

Use the following function as the way in your wordpress plugin file 
Use jQuery instead of $.

Answer (score 0):

can you please check this wordpress function for register and deregister javascript and css file in wwordpress code

please check this
 [Click Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Answer (score -2):

Download jquert-1.9.1 and put js file into your project an tha include that file using the script

on to the head part and than make a script tag ex

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$('id or class').click(function){
alert("click");
})
<script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i insert my plugin as shortcode into a page. So <html> and <head> tags are already there inside the page so how could i again put my js file in my plugin in html and head tags. i already tried that but same output comes...